# How to get JQuery DatePicker icon next to the TextBox input?

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I've been working on an ASP.net MVC application. I couldn't seem to get the `JQuery Datepicker` icon next to the text box.

[image]

Is there a fix for this? Many thanks.

View HTML

```
//View
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="padding: 4px; vertical-align:top;">
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            <input class="form-control" id="min" type="text" name="start" placeholder="Select a day of the week:" autocomplete="off" style="width:160px" readonly="readonly" />
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th style="padding: 4px; vertical-align:top;">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" formaction="/ScheduleView/SchCreate" formmethod="post" id="btnLoad" name="Load" value="Load Week" />
                    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" formaction="/ScheduleView/SchCreate" formmethod="post" id="btnApprove" name="Approve" value="Approve" />
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
}

//Datepicker JQuery
            $("#min").datepicker({
                autoHide: true,
                firstDay: 1,
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                minDate: new Date(ThisMonday),
                maxDate: new Date(sunday),
                showOn: "both",
                buttonText: "<i class='fa fa-calendar'></i>",
                onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, autoclose: true

            }).datepicker("setDate", new Date(STDate));
```

Comment: you can try with: $('#min').closest('span').find('.fa.fa-calendar')

Answer (score 1):

It is because class `form-control` has `display:block`:
[image]

Solution:

Add style to #min:

```
<style>
    #min {
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
```

result:

[image]

Or you can remove `class="form-control"`